# Infopath Form Web Part shifts/moves page off center

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath

As you can see in the image below, when the InfoPath web part is placed on the SharePoint page (SharePoint 2013), it moves the page content area of the center.

This has happened on multiple pages. I can't seem to find any information about why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Annotated screenshot]

Comment: Try centering Feebback and suggestions container div using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somehow a bug in SharePoint 2013 ([check here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5e98c323-330f-4e06-a48f-4a637577f384/infopath-form-web-part-breaking-page-left-alignment?forum=sharepointgeneral)). A quick resolution would be to add the following CSS to the page (in a hidden Content Editor WebPart or a Script Editor WebPart):

```
#sideNavBox { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in a script editor web part. Where it says WPQ2 change the 2 to the number of that webpart. You can find that by using Google Chrome inspect element. Modify the margins css to your liking.

```
<style type="text/css">
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 { 
margin-left:-200px;
margin-top:-150px; }
</style>
```